# android app crashes after permission disabling on API 23

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My app uses permissions

in app i'm asking **runtime permission** and it **works fine**

**BUT** when doing this steps

```
 1) using device home button going to current app settings page

 2) switching off permission

 3)then going back to app again with home button
```

it **crashes without any exception**

for exmaple **INSTAGRAM**  app

```
1) open instagram 

2) goto settings page

3) switch permission 

4)return to app
```

it restarts, i want to do  something like that

Comment: show error logcat

Comment: there is no exception

Comment: hi @Grigor_8263599! I have same problem! Did you find answer?

Comment: did you find the solution for  this

Answer (score 0):

To use CAMERA you have to check the permission at runtime.

All the [info are here.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

First check if the user grant the permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
```

Then, you could use this to request to the user:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to check for permission every time in code you are going to use the camera of memory functions 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

try this your need to **ask runtime permission** because **Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.**

ask runtime permission using below code

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.permission.CAMERA;
int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    String[] permission_list = new String[1];
    permission_list[0] = permission;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
}
```

**and than handle result like this**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             // perform your action here

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

read about [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: yes i have this, but when user disables from app, and . goto settings with home button, it crashes

Comment: didn't get you exaplain in brief and add your code in question

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Check for runtime permission every time you're trying to open the camera and in onRequestPermissionsResult() handle it properly if permission is denied. Do the same for memory permission also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // code here
}
```

in Manifest add **android:configChanges**

```
<activity
       android:name=".ui.edit.EditActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
      />
```

Comment: it doesn't help
when i'm going to settings page and watch android monitor it shows my app is dead