# android app needs restart after crash API 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

How I can avoid crashing my app on ***Android M*** like **Instagram** with current flow

1. open the Instagram app
2. goto app settings page, switch camera permission off
3. return to the app

as you see it **restarts** , but my app crashes without any exception

so I want make the same with my app

any ideas?

Comment: use try catch in your code.

Comment: Similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437339/how-to-restart-the-app-in-android-marshmallow-when-permission-changed-manually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically open the Permission Screen for a specific app on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

Comment: no, it's another problem ,it comes from here
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833688/android-app-crashes-after-permission-disabling-on-api-23